# Extracting data from Visual FoxPro databases

Tags: database

I just got some 20Gb of data in a Visual FoxPro database with a custom frontend probably written in the same framework, and need to extract that data in any well-known format. I don't know anything about VFP in particular, but as it is SQL, there should be a way of opening an SQL console, or maybe an `vfpdump` utility. How can I do that?

Everything I have now are a bunch of obscure binary files and a frontend executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dbview file.dbf > outfile.csv
```

or

```
dbf2mysql file.dbf > file.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? You could check out the [ODBC driver](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFPODBCDriver).

Comment: Yes, that frontend runs on Windows, but how can I 'connect' to the database consising of a several local files?

Comment: What are their file extensions? Anyway the ODBC driver should take care of them